# "ImportError: DLL load failed" when trying to use GDAL on Windows 7 64bit (Python 3.4.4 32bit)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, dll, gdal

**What I would like to do**

Installing GDAL on Windows7 64bit

**Precondition**

- Python 3.4.4 32bit 　(32 bit is necessary to combine other software with GDAL) installed
- Visual Studio C++2010 32bit and 64bit Redistributable package installed
- GDAL is downloaded from the following site:

  - http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7/mapserver-7.0.7-1600-core.msi
  - http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7/GDAL-2.2.3.win32-py3.4.msi

As for environment variables, I set the following three settings:

- PATH
- GDAL_DATA
- GDAL_DRIVER_PATH

**Error message**

```
=========== RESTART: C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\sample_program\sample.py ===========
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\sample_program\sample.py", line 2, in <module>
 from osgeo import gdal, gdalconst
 File "C:\Python34_32bit\lib\site-packages\osgeo\init.py", line 21, in <module>
 _gdal = swig_import_helper()
 File "C:\Python34_32bit\lib\site-packages\osgeo\init.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
 File "C:\Python34_32bit\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
 return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure can not be found
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting and added the error to the title. Also fixed the names of the environment variables.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
GDAL does not work because GDAL refers dll file which other software made before.(The dll file other software made is same name as GDAL's dll).
So, I fixed the dll path appropriately.Thanks.